# Move label to top of view with CA Layers and mask in Objective-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, subview

I would like to create tick marks for a graph done in Core Graphics.

The line graph is drawn CGPoint to CGPoint using a loop. However, there is also a gradient mask over the graph in a CALayer.

When I add the tickmarks as subviews on the graph, they are not appearing above the mask layer and instead are hidden below it.  How can I get the tick marks to appear above the mask layer.

```
//myPoints is an array of CGPoints
UIView *graph = [UIView new];
float yzero = graph.bounds.size.y; //this is the bottom of the graph or x axis
while (i < myPoints.count) {
    //calculate x and y for the point
    [linePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)];
    //Here I am trying to add tick mark
    UIView *tickview =[self makeLabelWith:@"|" atPoint:CGPointMake(x,yzero)];
    [graph addSubview:tickview];
    [graph bringSubviewToFront:tickview];
    i++;
}
```

The tick marks are getting created, but they are hidden by a mask.
Here is the code that creates the mask

```
CAGradientLayer* grad = [[CAGradientLayer alloc] init];
grad.frame = graph.bounds;
grad.colors = @[(id)[UIColor greenColor].CGColor,
                (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
    
CAShapeLayer* mask = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
mask.frame = graph.bounds;
mask.path = linePath.CGPath;
mask.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
grad.mask = mask;

[graph.layer addSublayer:grad];  
graph.clipsToBounds = YES;

//at the very end the graph is added to a large view that contains other things

[container addSubView:graph];
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: There is no such thing as "above" or "below" a mask. It's a mask. If you are masking out that area, you are masking it out.

Comment: So if you use assign a gradient layer to a view and a CAShape layer to that gradient layer as a mask, it blots out everything in that area?

Comment: Having read up on CALayers a bit, it appears that you can allow things to shine through by varying opacity in a mask but otherwise, the mask layer trumps other layers.  If I'm wrong please correct me. So I guess I will have to put the tick marks in the container in which the graph is embedded.

Comment: "in the container in which the graph is embedded" There you go.

Comment: Just a suggestion based on the assumption that you draw some of it using the graphical context and not ```UIView```s. Rather draw the ticks the same way, it is a bit of an overkill to draw them using views.